# Applescript Question: Repeat an action in MAIL on selected messages

Tags: macos, email, loops, applescript, repeat

Question: I would like to run an applescript against a list of selected messages in Apple OS X Mail.

Right now, the script I wrote will work on a single selection only, so I am guessing the issue is how to loop it for all items selected. Any help would be appreciated.

**Here is the script:**

```
tell application "Mail"

set theSelection to selection
set theSelectedMessage to item 1 of theSelection
set theSelectedMessageSender to sender of theSelectedMessage
set theSelectedMessageRecipient to address of to recipients of theSelectedMessage
set theSelectedMessageSenderName to extract name from sender of theSelectedMessage
set theSelectedMessageSenderAddress to extract address from sender of theSelectedMessage
set theSelectedMessageSubject to subject of theSelectedMessage
set theSelectedMessageContent to content of theSelectedMessage


set MessageText to ¬
"This email (" & theSelectedMessageRecipient & ") does NOT ¬
care to receive emails regarding this matter." & return & return & ¬
"This email was originally delivered to: " & ¬
theSelectedMessageRecipient & return & return & ¬
"Remove this email from your list: " & ¬
theSelectedMessageRecipient & ¬
return & return & ¬
"---------- ORIGINAL MESSAGE ----------------"

set theMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {visible:true, subject:"REMOVE: RE:" & theSelectedMessageSubject, content:MessageText & theSelectedMessageContent, reply to:theSelectedMessageRecipient}
tell theMessage
    make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {name:theSelectedMessageSenderName, address:theSelectedMessageSenderAddress}
end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set theSelectedMessage to item 1 of theSelection
```

Replace this with:

```
repeat with theSelectedMessage in theSelection
```

Just before the last line, add:

```
end repeat
```

Comment: Kindall, Thank you so much. I have been playing around with repeat loops for hours to get that to work. Rockstar!